# Contour Integral: $\int_{c} e^{(z+1/z)} dz$ where $c$ is a unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

From Cauchy's Residue theorem, I know that the value of integral is equal to:
$$2\pi*i*\sum{R}$$ where $R$=Residues of poles inside the contour.
And $z_0=0$ being the only residue inside the unit circle, I wrote the Laurent series of the function $f(z)= e^{(z+1/z)}$ which has coefficient of $1/z$ as a sum of series $(1+3+5+7+..=\infty)$. So the given integral blows up.

Need to confirm if my answer is correct or not.

Comment: Don't know how you got that sum.  The residue is$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!\,(k+1)!}$$which converges.

Comment: @David I will recheck my calculations. Thanks

Comment: @David Any idea how to evaluate the limit? Wolfram Alpha says its $I_1(2)$ Bessel function of first kind

Comment: No, no idea.  I got the same answer on Maple which I suspect means there is no "useful" simplification.  However, something to think about: is it a problem if there is no simplification?  Something like $e^\pi$ cannot be expressed by finitely many sums, differences, products, quotients of integers.  But we think it's an OK answer because we know lots about $\pi$ and lots about the exponential function.  The same is (potentially) true of Bessel functions.

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Instead of residue theorem consider that on the unit circle

$$\oint_C e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}dz = \oint_C e^{z+\bar{z}}dz$$

Then use the theorem

$$\oint_{\partial \Omega} f\:dz = 2i\iint\limits_\Omega \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\:dx dy$$

(where $z=x+iy$) and integrate over the disk in Cartesian coordinates. You will immediately get an integral representation of a Bessel function.